# Different results on Windows and Linux for ElAES.pas

Tags: pointers, delphi, winapi, encryption

I'm trying compile my project for Linux, have such code in ElAES.pas:

```
type
  TAESKey256 = array [0..31] of byte;
  TAESExpandedKey256 = array [0..63] of longword;
  PLongWord = ^LongWord;

procedure ExpandAESKeyForEncryption(const Key: TAESKey256; var ExpandedKey: TAESExpandedKey256); overload;
begin
  ExpandedKey[0] := PLongWord(@Key[0])^;
  ExpandedKey[1] := PLongWord(@Key[4])^;
  ExpandedKey[2] := PLongWord(@Key[8])^;
  ExpandedKey[3] := PLongWord(@Key[12])^;
  ExpandedKey[4] := PLongWord(@Key[16])^;
  ExpandedKey[5] := PLongWord(@Key[20])^;
  ExpandedKey[6] := PLongWord(@Key[24])^;
  ExpandedKey[7] := PLongWord(@Key[28])^;
```

And I have one result in ExpandedKey on Windows (32/64bit) and different result on Linux and MacOS. Key value is the same on both platforms. What I should change to get the same result on Linux/MAC like on Windows?

Comment: Pointers into subtypes is not portable across big/little endian operating systems.

Comment: Ok, on Windows ExKey[0] will be filled Key[0]Key[1]Key[2]Key[3] ? On Linux I should prepare another byte order in Key value for this to make it compatible? Key[3]Key[2]Key[1]Key[0] ?

Comment: @AlexEgorov you didn't explain how the `Key` is being filled to begin with, or why you think it is filled with integers. But consider using bitshifts instead of pointer dereferencing when building up your `ExpandedKey`. That will be more portable regardless of endian, eg: `ExpandedKey[0] := (LongWord(Key[0]) shl 24) or (LongWord(Key[1]) shl 16) or (LongWord(Key[2]) shl 8) or LongWord(Key[3]);` (or reverse the order of the `Key` indexes, if needed).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Key is filled with the same bytes on Windows and Linux, your suggesion I should use without '^': ExpandedKey[0] := LongWord(@Key[0]); but with this code I have different result in 'ExpandedKey' even on Windows, PLongWord(@Key[0])^ <> LongWord(@Key[0])

Comment: Using **pointers** with **encryption** indicates questionable understanding. Encode bytes, not Integers - then you don't deal with [endianess (BE vs LE vs ME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and platforms (16 bs 32 vs 64 bit).

Comment: @AlexEgorov "*your suggesion I should use without '^': ExpandedKey[0] := LongWord(@Key[0]);*" - that is not what I said to use. Go re-read my previous comment again more carefully. I'm taking the *value* of each byte, extending it to 32bit, and shifting its bits. You are simply casting a pointer to an integer. Not the same thing, not even close

Comment: @AmigoJack This code is not created by me, this is ElAES.pas file from Eldos software. Server side software used this unit and currently I need prepare Encryption and Decryption keys using this unit to get info from this server

Comment: @AlexEgorov then you need to contact Eldos for support, you should not be messing with their code. Let them fix whatever cross-platform issue you are having with their code.

Comment: If it's [ElAES.pas from 2001](https://github.com/AArhin/delphi-oop/blob/master/Persistence/Externals/NativeXml/extlib/eldos_aes/ElAES.pas) then its violation of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is alarming - I wouldn't use that code at all. And encode your bytes with a different tool to see if both even produce the same results.

Comment: Actually problem was not with LE/BE, but with the size of LongWord. Is it have 4 bytes on 32/64 bit Windows, but 8 bytes on POSIX 64 bit. After changing (P)LongWord to (P)UInt32 in whole unit all works fine now

Comment: @AlexEgorov good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, if the code works correctly in Win32, I test it in Win64. This helps catch errors related to different lengths of some types for 32 and 64 bits. This has always worked for me, but only until this case. The above code worked correctly in Win64. But there were errors when using in MacOS. The last thing I thought about was the difference in type sizes. And as it turned out - in vain. LongWord turned out to be a very strange type, the size of which is the same for Windows 32/64 bits and larger for Linux/MacOS. After changing the types in the module, everything worked on all platforms with any bit depth.

```
type
  TAESKey256 = array [0..31] of byte;
  TAESExpandedKey256 = array [0..63] of UInt32;
  PUInt32 = ^UInt32;

procedure ExpandAESKeyForEncryption(const Key: TAESKey256; var ExpandedKey: TAESExpandedKey256); overload;
begin
  ExpandedKey[0] := PUInt32(@Key[0])^;
  ExpandedKey[1] := PUInt32(@Key[4])^;
  ExpandedKey[2] := PUInt32(@Key[8])^;
  ExpandedKey[3] := PUInt32(@Key[12])^;
```